# C# Run external console application and no ouptut?

Tags: c#

in my project (MVC 3) I want to run an external console application using the following code:

```
   string returnvalue = string.Empty;

   ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\someapp.exe");
   info.UseShellExecute = false;
   info.Arguments = "some params";
   info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   info.CreateNoWindow = true;

   using (Process process = Process.Start(info))
   {
      StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;
      returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
   }
```

but I get an empty string in the `returnvalue` and that program creates a file as a result but there is not any file created. Maybe taht `Process` is not being executed ?

Comment: could it be piping it out to standard error?

Comment: Does your IIS apppool user has enough rights?

Comment: Not enough information. There is not file being created here and your questions are unclear.

Comment: If you do this, be aware that your site won't work in Medium Trust so you won't be able to host it most of the shared hosting environment companies.

Comment: Malcolm O'Hare - the project is being hosted on the VPS server

Comment: Daniel A. White - what do you mean 'standard error' ?

Comment: @Tony -> RedirectStandardError = true and then var errorReader = process.StandardError  -> read that you might get error output from the application

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, to read both standard error and standard output at the same time, you must do it with an async callback:

```
var outputText = new StringBuilder();
var errorText = new StringBuilder();
string returnvalue;

using (var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(
    "C:\\someapp.exe",
    "some params")
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        ErrorDialog = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }))
{
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, outLine) =>
        outputText.AppendLine(outLine.Data);

    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, errorLine) =>
        errorText.AppendLine(errorLine.Data);

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
    returnvalue = outputText.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + errorText.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for your external program to finish otherwise the output you want to read is not even generated when you want to read it.

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(info))
{
  if(process.WaitForExit(myTimeOutInMilliseconds))
  {
  StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;
  returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Comment: process.WaitForExit() it's a void function, not bool

Answer (score 0):

as TimothyP said in the comment, after setting `RedirectStandardError = true` and then via `process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` I get the error message content