# Executing an external program via c# without showing the console

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to run VLC from my C# Console Application, but I cannot. I know there are other similar questions (e.g. [Launching process in C# Without Distracting Console Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739101/launching-process-in-c-sharp-without-distracting-console-window) and [C# Run external console application and no ouptut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815747/c-sharp-run-external-console-application-and-no-ouptut) and [C#: Run external console program as hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430541/c-run-external-console-program-as-hidden)) and from them I derived the following code:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = " -I dummy";

        process.Start();
```

However, the console still shows up, both when I comment and uncomment the WindowStyle line. 
What's wrong?

Comment: What's VLC?  Is it possible that VLC is instantiating it's own console window?

Comment: It's http://www.videolan.org/. Yes, it might be actually. Via -I dummy i avoid the UI to start.

Comment: I installed VLC and tried `-I dummy` from the command line.  It does launch a 2nd window.  It seems you may need to programmatically find that window and hide it.

Comment: Uhm... agat suggested the use of FindWindow, but I cannot get it hidden: I think I cannot find it by name. Also, if I drop -I dummy, the normal UI starts; if I look for the name, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command line switch. It's documented [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help).

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-I dummy --dummy-quiet";
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/ea8b0fd5-a660-46f9-9dcb-d525cc22dcbd/hide-console-window-in-c-console-application?forum=csharpgeneral), just do the following:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,string lpWindowName);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

...

     //Sometimes System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath works for the caption depending on the system you are running under.
     IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Your console windows caption"); //put your console window caption here
     if(hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
     {
        //Hide the window
        ShowWindow(hWnd, 0); // 0 = SW_HIDE
     }


     if(hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
     {
        //Show window again
        ShowWindow(hWnd, 1); //1 = SW_SHOWNORMA
     }
```

### updated:

You also should add WaitForInputIdle after the process starting:

```
process.Start();
process.WaitForInputIdle();
```

Comment: Still showing. I added the DllImport in the class definition and the following code within the Main method. No luck. I can only hide the launching application, not the launched one.

Comment: Yes. Right, you should look for the executed application window, not executing.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and I inserted C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\VLC\\vlc.exe as caption to look for, but it doesn't seem to work. I actually don't even know how to change the caption of the externally run process.

Comment: Hm... But the window caption won't be the path. You should find it somehow in another way. Try something like this: http://superuser.com/questions/378790/how-to-get-window-title-in-windows-from-shell.

Comment: It says the name is C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\VLC\vlc.exe

Comment: Ok. I've tried all the stuff... and now it even works for me. You should also add this line: process.WaitForInputIdle(); after process.Start();

Comment: nope, still not doing right. However, the solution proposed in my accepted answer fixed the problem. Thank you for your advice on FindWindow, it was still useful!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the Output type in the project properties to Windows Application.
Just go right click on the project > properties > Application

Comment: That doesn't work: the issue is with an externally launched process.

Comment: That's weird, it works fine for me, maybe there is a problem with the VLC itself? try launching a different program.